# Custom weights and training of Neural Network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, feed-forward

Consider this Neural Network:

[My Neural Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEUsb.png)

the numbers which are on connections in this Neural Network, show the connection weights and numbers on each node (neuron) are thresholds of hard-lim transfer function.

Now here are my two questions:

**First:** for implementing this neural network I used below code, but I couldn't specify connection weights. How can I specify them?

```
net=feedforwardnet([2,4]);
net.numInputs=2;
net.inputConnect=[1 1;0 0;0 0];
net.inputs{1}.size=4;
net.inputs{2}.size=4;
net.layers{3}.size=2
view(net)
```

**Second:** `(x1,x2)` is the coordinate of input dots and this Neural Network specify if this dot belong to `s1` or `s2`. For example:

```
(3,3)∈s2
(0,1)∈s2
(1,3)∈s1
(4,1)∈s1
```

now how should I train this neural network for this kind of inputs and targets?

(I use MATLAB R2014a and am a little new in MATLAB Neural Network, so please be kind)

Any suggestion will help so much. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Connection weights in the neural network are learnt during training, why do you wish to set them manually?

Comment: @kedarps I've used one particular algorithm to find the best custom neural network for one special dataset. So I need to compare this custom neural network against that one which start from for example random connection weights in performance.

Comment: Ok. Can you compare performance of the two networks?

Comment: I am trying to do that...